# Logging into ArcGIS Online for Organizations from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-online

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1 for Desktop and have access to ArcGIS Online for Organizations.

Is there any way I can log into ArcGIS Online for Organizations from ArcMap?

Answer (score 3):

Under the File menu, see the Sign In option:

[image]

Once you've signed in, you will be able to add data to ArcMap from ArcGIS Online - rather than hitting the + of the Add Data button, use the dropdown beside it:

[image]

You will also see My Hosted Services in the ArcCatalog window:

[image]

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for your response. I tried it before but it doesn't work. With my AGO subscription account, I have to sign in at this address http://abc.maps.arcgis.com/ (abc represents the name of my organization) instead of arcgis.com. Is there any other tips?

Comment: Sorry, not sure - my situation is the same as yours. What error message do you get when you try this approach?

Comment: It says invalid username or password. I am sure that I get the username and password right. I guess it is because my organization is using cloud environment provided by Amazon to ensure security rather than the ESRI cloud-based server.

Comment: No idea, sorry. I would raise this with whoever set up your Amazon infrastructure, and/or with your local Esri support person as it appears that it hasn't been configured correctly